# Insert a new instance of a component onClick outside DOM hierarchy of the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I would like to **create** a new component( `<CreateLine/>`) every time the user clicks as opposed to updating underlying element in the existing DOM node.

```
// onClick to create a separate instance of the CreateLine Component and insert it to the Create Area as a Child. 


    <AddCircleSharpIcon onClick={ () => {
    
        ReactDOM.render( 
    
   <CreateLine
   type={type} title={title} line={line}
    color={color}
    data={[...data]} 
    />,
    
document.getElementById("CreateArea")

)

}}
```

// 2ND UPDATE STILL CANT GET IT TO WORK. N number of lines show but with the same options `(type,title,line,color and data)`. How can I get around this :)

```
      const [numberofLines, setnumberofLines] = useState([0]); 
    

        <AddCircleSharpIcon onClick={ () => {
        
      setnumberofLines([...numberofLines, numberofLines.length])

}}
function LineComponent() {

  return (

    <React.Fragment>

      {numberofLines.map( (si) => (

           <CreateLine
   type={type} title={title} line={line}
    color={color}
    data={[...data]} 
    />,
            
      )) }

</React.Fragment> 
  )
}
```

// Using useEffect beacuse im running nextJs SSR.

```
useEffect( () => {

ReactDOM.render(<LineComponent />, document.getElementById("CreateArea"))

}, [numberofLines])
```

Comment: Generally, a Portal is preferred if you want to mount a component outside the root of your tree. If the parent component is close to the add button, you can maintain an array of component and add/remove elements to it.

Comment: I did think of an array of components to loop through but I was unsure of implementation. I'll take a stab at it :)

Comment: You can create an array with an item that has some sort of id and required data (maybe some label or something) and then whenever add button is clicked just add a new item with a new unique Id and data. Removal is just reverse. :+1

Comment: I think my issue is that it's replacing the underlying existing element in "CreateArea" div.

Comment: you are doing it in the wrong place. You only use ReactDOM.render once and use `useState` instead of useRef. Changing useRef doesn't trigger the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to add new lines every time you click the button. It is a mock code so you can fill the remaining bits and pieces.

```
function LineComponent() {
  const [numberOfLines, setNumberOfLines] = useState([]);
  const addNewLine = () => {
    setNumberOfLines(prevLines => ([
      ...prevLines,
      {
        ...newData // add your new data here
      }
    ]))
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AddCircleSharpIcon onClick={addNewLine}
      {numberOfLines.map(line => (
        <CreateLine key={line.id} type={line.type} title={line.title} line={line} color={line.color} data={line.data} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment> 
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<LineComponent />, document.getElementById("CreateArea"))
```

Comment: I'm very close to getting it done. I think the remaining "part" is setting the setnumberofLines state object to include the options for every line. ?

Comment: Yeah. You can add your object where newData is written.

Comment: @Ibra if it answers your question, please mark it as accepted answer.